# Bug in PL/pgSQL function creation

Tags: postgresql, cursors, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.3

I don't know if this question better suits here or in SO ...

This is a script that I'd like to launch (the code of the function was copied [from a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database)):

```
\c mydb

create or replace function truncate_tables(username in varchar) returns void as $$
declare
    stmt RECORD;
    statements cursor for select tablename from pg_tables where tableowner = username;
begin 
    for stmt in statements loop
        execute 'truncate table ' || quote_ident(stmt.tablename) || ' CASCADE ;';
    end loop;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax at or near "$1"    LINE1:   $1
QUERY $1
CONTEXT: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "truncate_tables" near line 5
```

I am new to Postgres and PL/pgSQL and don't know what this error message means.

Comment: It's a third party database. Just to explain the context: I want to be able to backup production databases onto our developement databases for debugging and diagnose... and it seems I have to truncate all our local tables before restoring, otherwise pg_restore thows hundreds of errors because of dupplicate keys.

Comment: "...it seems I have to truncate all our local tables before restoring..." The pg_dump utility can drop database objects before trying to create them. See the --clean argument on [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-pgdump.html).  Depending on your environment, it might be practical to drop the dev database before restoring to it. (Make sure the dump creates the database before you do *that*.)

Comment: @Catcall, I'm dumping production databases and I don't want them to be cleared. What's updated I want to restore in developement databases, on which we can diagnose and debug.

Comment: @Stephane I don't think Catcall is referring to clearing the source database - rather generating sql to [drop and recreate the tables in the development database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2089668/533832).

Comment: hmm, I am gonna try this solution too ;)

Comment: Sadly, the answers for the [question at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database) where you got your advice from were not very good (IMO). I added an alternative answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try dispensing with the explicit cursor:

```sql
begin;
set role dba;
create role stack;
grant stack to dba;
create schema authorization stack;
set role stack;
--
create table foo(id serial);
insert into foo default values;
create or replace function truncate_tables(username in varchar) returns void as $$
declare r record;
begin 
    for r in (select tablename from pg_tables where tableowner = username) loop
        execute 'truncate table ' || quote_ident(r.tablename) || ' cascade';
    end loop;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
--
select truncate_tables('stack');
select * from foo;
/*
 id
----
(0 rows)
*/
--
rollback;
```

Comment: also check you can run `select tablename from pg_tables where tableowner = 'foo'` as the user running the script

Comment: Bingo ! Does that mean that PL/PgSql doesn't support cursors ?

Comment: I'm trying to find some doc on cursor limitation in 8.3. Maybe that's a known issue.

Comment: All in all... for the moment I have found no limitation regarding cursors in 8.3 in documentation. Once again many thx Jack!

Comment: Detail you might be interested in: Unlike [`expression IN (subquery)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) in SQL, [`FOR target IN query LOOP`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) in plpgsql does not require parenthesis around the query.

Comment: @Erwin thanks - I'm glad I know that now. We still don't know why the Stephane got an error, have you got 8.3 to test on?

Comment: Sorry, the oldest I've got is 8.4. I tested the OP's code there and it works as is. I am fresh out of ideas.

Answer (score 5):

This particular example can be simpler.
You can `TRUNCATE` multiple tables at once. Aggregate all tablenames and execute a single statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION truncate_tables(_username text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
      SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE '
             || string_agg(quote_ident(t.tablename), ', ')
             || ' CASCADE;'
      FROM   pg_tables t
      WHERE  t.tableowner = _username
      AND    t.schemaname = 'public'
   );
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT truncate_tables('postgres');
```

`string_agg()` requires PostgreSQL **9.0** or later.
In 8.4 you can substitute:

```
array-to_string(array_agg(quote_ident(t.tablename)), ', ')
```

For v8.3 you would write your own aggregate function - rather simple, yet not simpler than the looping solution any more.

---

Performance degrades when deleting or truncating *many* tables at once in PostgreSQL 9.1. A fix for this in the upcoming version 9.2. I quote [the release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/release-9-2.html#AEN110326):

> Improve performance of checkpointer's fsync-request queue when many
>   tables are being dropped or truncated (Tom Lane)

[Related thread at pgsql-hackers.](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMkU=1x36-xLdUORNZCXZh4yt+qC0z+Qqcyj7Y-gfPgFt2w2FA@mail.gmail.com)

[@Craig's related answer at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11423886/939860) helped me discover this.

Comment: +1 excellent. As you say elsewhere, simpler and faster.